# Prolog - Recursive List

Tags: list, recursion, prolog

Here is my question:
A small club decided to set up a telephone network for urgent messages
amongst its members. The following arrangement was agreed:
Anne can phone both Bill and Mary. Bill can phone both Tom
and Sue. Tom can phone both Liz and Frank. Liz can also phone
Frank if necessary.

Express this information as seven Prolog facts of the form
`can_phone(anne,bill)`. Now write recursive Prolog rules for a predicate message_route such
that `message_route(A,B,R)` is true if `A` can pass a message to `B` routed
via the people in list `R`, using the club’s telephone arrangements. For
example, `message_route(anne,frank,[anne,bill,tom,liz,frank])`
would be true (because `anne` can phone `bill`, who can phone `tom`,
who can phone `liz`, who can phone `frank`).

I have this so far:

```
can_phone(anne,bill).
can_phone(anne,mary).
can_phone(bill,tom).
can_phone(bill,sue).
can_phone(tom,liz).
can_phone(tom,frank).
can_phone(liz,frank).
```

For my `message_route`, I have experimented and have this working which allows me to complete the second part of the question without the requirement of restricting the list to a specified list of persons (`R`).

```
message_route(A,B) :- can_phone(A,B).
message_route(A,B) :- can_phone(A,X), message_route(X,B).
```

I don't understand how to implement this list in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accumulating a list is relatively straightforward: first, observe that if `A` can call `B` directly, the list is simply `[A, B]`. Hence, we can rewrite your first rule as

```
message_route(A,B,[A,B]) :- can_phone(A,B).
```

The second rule is a bit trickier: you need to unify to a list produced by `message_route`, and insert `A` at its head. Note that you do not need to insert `X` or `B`, because they would be provided by the returned list:

```
message_route(A,B,[A|Tail]) :- can_phone(A,X), message_route(X,B,Tail).
```

Here is a [small demo that uses your data](http://ideone.com/eHjE7q).

Note that this code would be chasing its own tail if the data that you present represents a graph with loops, rather than a tree. To avoid this, you could avoid picking `X` if it is already part of the `Tail` list.

Comment: can_phone does not need the third variable.

Comment: @VincentRamdhanie Thanks! I tried the code, and found the same error.

Comment: Thank you, I am still confused as how to write message_route with the prototype message_route(A,B,R) as written in the question. Regards.

Comment: @DannyRancher You can unify `R` to `[A|Tail]` in the body of the rule, like this: `message_route(A,B,R) :- can_phone(A,X), message_route(X,B,Tail), R = [A|Tail].` That's the same thing - my guess is that the question asked for `R` to avoid giving you an implementation hint.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I attempted to unify R. Am I doing it correctly.
message_route(A,B,[A,B]) :- can_phone(A,B).
message_route(A,B,[A|Tail]) :- can_phone(A,X), message_route(X,B,Tail).
% message_route(A,B,R) :- can_phone(A,B,R), R = [A,B].
% message_route(A,B,R) :- can_phone(A,B,R), can_phone(A,X), message_route(X,B,Tail), R = [A|Tail].

Comment: @DannyRancher Take a look at the modified demo: [link](http://ideone.com/BseskL).

Comment: @dasblinkenlight thank you. a final comment, why does message_route(anne,frank,[bill,tom,liz]). return false?

Comment: @DannyRancher Because in order for this rule to unify, the first element of the list must match `A`, and the last element of the list must match `B`. Add them to the beginning and to the end of the list to get a match: `message_route(anne,frank,[anne, bill, tom, liz, frank])`

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I was under the impression that R represented the list of the routers not including the sender and receiver of the message.

Comment: @DannyRancher That's an easy change: use an empty list in the "base" predicate, and prepend `X` instead of `A` in the recursive rule ([link](http://ideone.com/geekzs)).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25795/discussion-between-danny-rancher-and-dasblinkenlight)